# scrape Url and text from website using lxml python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I don't know much about lxml and xpaths and I want to learn how to scrape data from website. When I run this code I don't get any results and don't know why. Please help me to fix it.

code here

```
from lxml import html
import requests
pageLen=str(100)
page = requests.get('http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=lawyer&geo_location_terms=usa&page=2')
print(page)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
#phoneNumber = tree.xpath('//span[@class="c411Phone"]/text()')
Link=tree.xpath('//div[@class="info"]/a/@href')
Bname=tree.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]/text()')
print(Bussiness_names)
print(Bname)
```

HTML CODE

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Beautiful Soup? http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/

Comment: I did not try beautiful soap. can not I extract link using lxml?

Comment: You need to go and learn about xpaths and read the lxml documentation if you have no idea how either works.

Comment: Can you suggest me any good book or tutorial?

Comment: The lxml docs which are extensive come in pdf format http://lxml.de/3.4/lxmldoc-3.4.4.pdf, w3schools has a good xpath tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=lawyer&geo_location_terms=usa&page=2'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
tree.make_links_absolute(url)
for business in tree.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]'):
  print business.attrib['href'], business.text
```

Comment: Changed the 2nd script to python 2.7

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get url ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Abd Azrad. Your solution helped me a lot.

Can you please further guide me? I am confused how to deal with inconsistent data? 
Sometimes, there are postal address missing and sometimes location missing. I just want to ignore that data which does not fulfill my requirements.

        `page = requests.get('http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=%s&geo_location_terms=%s&page=%s'%("lawyer","toronot","2"))
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        bus_names=tree.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]/text()')
        print bus_names
        ##bus_url=tree.xpath('//a[@class="business-name"]/href()')
        ##print bus_url
        street_ad=tree.xpath('//span[@class="street-address"]/text()')
        print(street_ad)
        loc=tree.xpath('//span[@class="locality"]/text()')
        print(loc)
        postal=tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()')
        print(postal)
        contact=tree.xpath('//div[@class="phones phone primary"]/text()')
        print(contact)`

In this way I am getting list and I failed to keep track data because lists lenght is not same. Is there any way to get data of every person in list and all data in form of 2d list [[person_one_name,person_one_address],[person_two_name,person_two_contact]]?

Comment: Sadly this website isn't really set up for this kind of ongoing help. I recommend posting a new question. But here is some general advice: Use a dictionary to store each business (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python). 
Use `try` and `except` to deal with missing data (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except).